# Chrome's Flash cache on Windows

Tags: google-chrome, flash, cache

My C drive is running out of space and sometimes when viewing large flash vidio on Chrome there is notification that the disk is running low. I want to change the cache location of such flash cache files to ramdisk. I found something like this:
%appdata%\Adobe\Flash Player
but this doesn't seems to be the location I am looking for. Does anyone know the correct directory of such cache?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are referring to your drive as "C" drive, i assume you are using windows.

You can use [this software](http://memory.dataram.com/products-and-services/software/ramdisk) to solve your problem. (if you dont already have a ramdisk solution).

Finally, add `--disk-cache-dir="E:\BrowserCache"` to your chrome shortcut, where "E" stands for your ramdisk drive.

Comment: Thanks, actually I already configured ramdisk, what I wish to know is the location of the flash cache on chrome I mentioned.

Comment: answer is updated

Comment: Hmm I also did this but seems like Flash cache is stored separately from other cache.